# Unable to call a specific form from a button in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have a form designed in GUI designer. I call it "Register" to collect information for new member registration. Some how whenever I try to open this form using showForm("Register",null), I get this error -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:394)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.getFormState(UIBuilder.java:1711)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.showForm(UIBuilder.java:2195)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.showForm(UIBuilder.java:2263)
```

I have not been able to find any reason for this. Is Register a reserved name? What other thing can cause this? Please help, I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using an older version of Codename One, you need to update your client libraries in the preferences.

This can happen if you showed your current form manually (not via the GUI builder), there is a bug in the current version where showForm() tries to get the name of the currently showing form and doesn't check for null. To workaround this just use `setName()` on the current form or make sure that all your forms are shown via the GUI builder.

Comment: All my forms are shown via guy builder. It is only this form that is not showing. I will try the setName90 but this will be in the current form.

Comment: Right click project, select preferences. Select the Codename One section (if its not selected by default) Button on bottom right corner, update libraries.