# Form elements are not receiving input

Tags: codenameone

I have a form designed with the GUI designer with input textfields and buttons. I have attached actions to the buttons. When I call up the form with showForm(Form,null), the textfields are not accepting input and the buttons are not triggering the action. This is happening only for this form. Initially, there was the problem solved here [Unable to call a specific form from a button in codenameone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258332/unable-to-call-a-specific-form-from-a-button-in-codenameone) and then the problem solved here [Simulator keeps defaulting to old Main form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390128/simulator-keeps-defaulting-to-old-main-form). What could be the issue now?

Comment: question unclear... can you provide the code sample ??

Comment: Which code sample? The code generated by the GUI designer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there may be some issues as you say, but first need to see code

Answer (score 0):

In the form after you added the text fields did you select the text field component and press action event?

Assuming you did that you should get a callback method in the Statemachine class.

This call will be invoked only when the user changes the content of the text field. You can run in the debugger and set breakpoints/step into code to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks but there was all the callbacks. I have now fixed it by adding a new button, generating action code for the new button and running. After that , I removed the new button. I am not sure why that solved the problem.

Comment: Its too vague for me to answer properly. When you don't have code to show a few screenshots go a long way to illustrate your issue.